# Dingo api not registering routes

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, dingo-api

Hi i'm using Dingo Api dev-master b36db17 (1.0.*@dev) with Laravel 5.2.11

When i try to acces my api routes i get an error :

```
"The version given was unknown or has no registered routes." (status:400)
```

here is my api route:

```
$api = app('Dingo\Api\Routing\Router');

$api->version('v1', ['version' => 'v1', 'prefix' => 'api'], function ($api) {

  Route::group(['prefix' => 'api', 'version' => 'v1'], function () {
    //# Version 1 routes here
    Route::post('login', [  
      'uses'      => 'App\Api\V1\Http\Controllers\AuthenticateController@authenticate',
      'as'        => 'api.login'
      ]);
  });
});
```

the command `php artisan api:routes` shows nothing

I need some help please

Edit - 27/01/16

What is the purpose of the adapter ?

it looks like the routes are not loaded :

class Laravel implements Adapter in namespace Dingo\Api\Routing\Adapter

```
public function dispatch(Request $request, $version)
{
    if (! isset($this->routes[$version])) {
        var_dump($this->routes);
        throw new UnknownVersionException;
    }
    [...]
}
```

Comment: what is the purpose of the class Laravel implementation of Adapter ?

Answer (score 0):

problem auto-resolved : 
to declare my routes, i used the Route facade instead of the Dingo api router (Dingo has its own router since a recent version)

so i replaced `Route::group(` and `Route::get(`

by `$api->get(` and `$api->get(`